# Ubuntu 18.04 does not show GUI and freezes on startup

Tags: amd-graphics, gdm, amd-processor

I have bought a new laptop Asus tuf.
Below is config for same:

- ASUS TUF FX505DY-BQ002T 15.6-inch FHD Gaming Laptop
- AMD Ryzen 5-3550H/8GB
- 1TB HDD
- Windows 10
- Radeon RX 560X 4GB Graphics
- 2.20 Kg

After dual boot when I choose Ubuntu and tried login, Ubuntu freezes and doesn't show login screen.
I did <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and logged in using grub and checked system logs using `journalctl -b` and got an error

> Error was "gLib: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed

Can someone please help. I have tried all of the solutions I could find using Google, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try other distro like xubuntu,kubuntu as gdm gives problem sometimes.I think it's distro's problem not hardware's.Try other distro.

Comment: Don't use ubuntu 18.04 .try 18.10 atleast. I am also going to buy this.Please tell how it works.Your problem is about ubunu not hardware.try other distro.

Comment: But I am able to boot using recovery mode.

Comment: Hi I am able to see login screen once I set nomodeset in grub. But without I still get same error. Could it be problem related to graphics card.

Comment: Did you try other distro?Please try.

Comment: I tried other distribution. This laptop uses And RX 560x graphics card which doesn't support ubuntu

Comment: It has integrated graphics too named Vega 8.It is well supported.

Comment: I am having the same problem using ubuntu studio. I have been using for yrs and now It wont work on: 
    Processor - Ryzen 5 3550H
    Screen size - 17.3 Inch Full HD Screen
    Graphics card - Radeon Vega RX560X 4GB
    RAM - 8GB
    SSD - 1TB Hard Drive + 256GB
    Operating System - Windows 10
    Warranty - 1 year warranty
    Graphic Type - Dedicated
just stalls and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I want to buy this. Please try other distro.
However,I think it is not graphics problem.Amdgpu has full support for Linux and it's GPUs and there is no need to disable kms

Comment: It doesn't have. Rx 560X not supported

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470351/rx-560x-slower-than-integrated-vega-gpu-on-fedora-28

The issue is with kernel not supporting GPU but has been solved in latest kernel(5.0) Since you are using Ubuntu (not latest kernel I assume) You cannot run using Dedicated GPU.

So,you must choose distro with latest kernel and Manjari is the option I recommend .Please try and reply

Hope this helps....

Comment: Hi Varshit, Tried installing manjaro but getting multiple error and it doesn't even install.

Comment: I wanted best laptop without nvidia and probably i7 graphics.Felt sad on this laptop.

Comment: I have gotten in touch with RMD support and they said they don't know by when they will be able to release a graphic card for Linux.

Comment: Is there anything else I can try

Comment: Hi @Varshit it worked with Ubuntu 19.04 . If you are planning to purchase go ahead as issue is resolved

Comment: Hi Varshit I am able to boot Ubuntu 19.04 in my laptop without doing anything